# Progressive fetch or all at once Master Detail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-router, graphql

I am making a master-detail-detail application in React and GraphQL.  Let me explain, there is a sidebar which shows products, and then when you click one of the list of products, ANOTHER list is shown in the main window (Master Detail). Here is the kicker, if you click one of the products in the Main window ANOTHER section on the right sidebar is populated with details.  So like this:

Master List --> Details List --> Properties of Detail

I have React Router set up nicely and wondering what is the proper way to fetch?  There are many ideas about this.  For instance, should I structure the call and data for GraphQL to just fetch EVERYTHING onLoad?  i.e. Parents (products), Children (product list), and details (details of children.  Just fetch everything and setState?

OR, is the proper way to do things using GraphQL, to load ONLY the product list when the application loads, and when a user clicks on a product THEN FETCH the list of children, and when they click a child product, THEN fetch the details.

Just wondering about methodology.... of course when the lists get big, you would have a spinner show in the main pane, and then a spinner show in the details pane I suppose.

GraphQL solves the overFetching situation.... but, should I divide the fetch up when a user clicks and progressively fetch...or fetch everything at once and just click -> map() over the results.

I am curious to hear everyone's take on this.

Comment: This is a good question but not really suitable for SO since it's likely to only generate opinion-based answers. You might consider posing this question to a more different community (for example, [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/graphql))

Comment: Respectfully, I have to disagree about it's suitability.  It is a straightforward coding question about breaking up GraphQL requests vs. fetching all at once.

Comment: Point taken though.  I need to understand the use of GraphQL better.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to not fetch the entire JSON tree at once.  That would be a huge overfetch. We can create separate collections in MongoDB for the parent items and the child items in a one-to-many relationship, then use GraphQL to fetch exactly what we need in each window onClick/onChange.  This seems the most efficient and expedient way since I am dealing with upwards of 10 panes of data and around 50 components. This is a very complex application I am working on.

Comment: FWIW, you can also take a look at [prefetching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/performance/#prefetching-data) as way of improving the UX while keeping your initial load minimal.